# How can use in Inertia the language translation

Tags: php, laravel, inertiajs

i have a problem with Vue3 and Inertia

In normal laravel i can use:

```
<a>{{ __('hello.there') }}</a>
```

I tried it with `:` but that also don't work.
I don't know what to do since this is how it should work. But it does not. Is that no longer possible with the language files?

Comment: Use it to do _what_? Is "hello.there" just the name of a translation string, or some special notation?

Comment: you can use i18n